# Calculate Frequency of Letter in String and TF-IDF

Tags: r, text, tm, tf-idf

I have a named character vector called `y` that looks similar to this -

```
D1        D2        D3        D4        D5 
 "X D X "  "G U V "   "F Q  " "A C U E"  "H I T "
```

What I would like to do with this vector is create both the frequency counts of the Letters and also the IDF weighting. I tried to run this code:

```
dd <- Corpus(VectorSource(y)) #Make a corpus object from a text vector
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(dd, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
```

However, when I run this code I get the error:

```
Warning message:
In weighting(x) : empty document(s): 1 2 3 4 5.
```

All of the documents have Letters or at least even a white space (I also want included in the counts). I am not sure what I am doing wrong - I was able to get this example working - [Different tf-idf values in R and hand calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011395/different-tf-idf-values-in-r-and-hand-calculation).

Using my example above what I would like is something like this:

```
A C D E F G H I Q T U V X
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 - D1
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 - D2
...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I changed my answer to provide tf-idf since the question changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in base R:

```
y <- c("X D X ",  "G U V ",   "F Q  ", "A C U E",  "H I T ")
names(y) <- paste0("D", 1:5)
# named vector of strings
y
D1        D2        D3        D4        D5 
"X D X "  "G U V "   "F Q  " "A C U E"  "H I T " 

# get rid of spaces, then split every letter
let <- sapply(y, function(x) strsplit(gsub(" ", "", x), ""))
# all possible letters
let_all <- unique(unlist(let))
# uses table on factored x with all possible levels
let_tab <- sapply(let, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=let_all)))
# with some cosmetics
t(let_tab[order(rownames(let_tab)), ])

   A C D E F G H I Q T U V X
D1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
D2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
D3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
D4 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
D5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

is this what you want? if yes, a function that does all of this:

```
tabulate_letters <- function(y){
  let <- sapply(y, function(x) strsplit(gsub(" ", "", x), ""))
  # all possible letters
  let_all <- unique(unlist(let))
  # uses table on factored x with all possible levels
  let_tab <- sapply(let, function(x) table(factor(x, levels=let_all)))
  # with some cosmetics
  t(let_tab[order(rownames(let_tab)), ])
}

tabulate_letters(y)

   A C D E F G H I Q T U V X
D1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
D2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
D3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
D4 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
D5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this also using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(y, ' '))[-1]
#   A C D E F G H I Q T U V X
#D1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
#D2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#D3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#D4 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#D5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

We could remove the leading/lagging spaces with `trimws` before doing the `strsplit`.

```
mtabulate(strsplit(trimws(y), " "))
```

#### data

```
y <- c("X D X ",  "G U V ",   "F Q  ", "A C U E",  "H I T ")
names(y) <- paste0("D", 1:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that: the **quanteda** package.

```
require(quanteda)
y <- c("X D X ",  "G U V ",   "F Q  ", "A C U E",  "H I T ")

dtm <- dfm(y, toLower = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
# sort by letter, if that's important
dtm <- dtm[, sort(features(dtm))]
dtm
## Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 13 features.
## 5 x 13 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    A C D E F G H I Q T U V X
##   text1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
##   text2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
##   text3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
##   text4 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
##   text5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

If you want *tf-idf*, that's easy too:

```
tfidf(dtm)
## Document-feature matrix of: 5 documents, 13 features.
## 5 x 13 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs          A       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       Q       T       U       V       X
##   text1 0       0       0.69897 0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1.39794
##   text2 0       0       0       0       0       0.69897 0       0       0       0       0.39794 0.69897 0      
##   text3 0       0       0       0       0.69897 0       0       0       0.69897 0       0       0       0      
##   text4 0.69897 0.69897 0       0.69897 0       0       0       0       0       0       0.39794 0       0      
##   text5 0       0       0       0       0       0       0.69897 0.69897 0       0.69897 0       0       0
```